# ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run the tutorial in [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/googlecodelabs/odml-pathways/blob/main/audio_classification/colab/model_maker_audio_colab.ipynb#scrollTo=wbMc4vHjaYdQ)

```
!pip install tflite-model-maker tensorflow==2.5
```

Getting the error for cell-2:

```
Collecting tflite-model-maker
  Downloading tflite_model_maker-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (577 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 577.3/577.3 kB 7.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.5 (from versions: 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1, 2.13.0rc2, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.14.0rc0, 2.14.0rc1, 2.14.0, 2.14.1, 2.15.0rc0, 2.15.0rc1, 2.15.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.5
```

What's wrong and how to resolve it?

Comment: Its easy to check which version of Python you would need to install TensorFlow 2.5: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.5.0/ you need Python 3.9-3.11.

Answer (score 1):

So you're using Google Colab and it supports TensorFlow versions above 2.8.0rc0, you can specify a TensorFlow version higher than 2.8.0.

> versions: 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4,
> 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1, 2.13.0rc2, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.14.0rc0, 2.14.0rc1, 2.14.0, 2.14.1, 2.15.0rc0, 2.15.0rc1, 2.15.0

These are the versions you can use in colabs

Comment: Version 2.9.0 is installing for indefinite time and my storage gets exceeded within short time. I am tuning colab non premium (storage upto 75GB) :(